# Convert third degree ODE into system of first order ODES

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following:

$$
y'''+10001y''+10000y'=0
$$
The following is obtained:
$$
x_{1}' = x_{2}
$$

$$
x_{2}' = x_{3}
$$
$$
x_{3}' = -(10001x_{3} + 10000x_{2})
$$
I left out $x_{1} = y$ which is how I established everything. Does doing this effect my results in any way? Can I leave this out to keep it a $3x3$ system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine.  In fact, you can ignore the first equation $x_1'=x_2$ as well and view it as a second order system in $y'$, solve that, and integrate later to get $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In fact, you have to leave $x_{1}$ out of the resulting 1st-order system, because $y$ itself does not even appear in the original ODE.  Only derivatives of $y$ appear.